# What does Actor[akka:\\play\deadLetters].tell() mean in a New Relic's trace of a Play Framework 2.0 web transaction?

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, newrelic

[image: Screenshot from New Relic]

I have a Play Framework 2.0 Java application hosted on Heroku, and I am monitoring it using the free-tier New Relic addon. For most of the transactions, a majority of the time is spent in what New Relic labels as `Actor[akka:\\play\deadLetters].tell()`. What is the application actually doing during this time?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple description, Akka (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akka_(toolkit); http://akka.io/) is part of the Play framework as one of their integrations. As the application on Play is instrumented for monitoring there are HTTP requests made by Akka that are traced as a web transaction.  In short, we measure it.  As for what is is specifically doing, I recommend checking the Play documentation or the Akka link from the first sentence.

If you have a Java agent version older than 3.2.0, upgrading the Java agent will give you the following change:

> akka.actor.ActorKilledException is now ignored by default
>
> The ActorKilledException is commonly thrown in Play applications as a
>   control mechanism in normally functioning applications. In previous
>   versions, this exception inflated the reported error rate. These
>   exceptions are now ingored by default. You can override the default
>   ignore_errors list to provide your own exceptions or to omit the
>   ActorKilledException.

Let us know if this information is helpful or if you need additional assistance.

Jeanie Swan
New Relic Support

Comment: Hi Jeanie, thanks for finding me on stackoverflow. I upgraded the New Relic agent to version 3.3.2, and I still see the same thing.

Comment: Did you restart the JVM along with upgrading the agent?  If not, it won't pick up the new version.

Comment: Yes, any Heroku deploy restarts the JVM. The best I can figure is that some part of my application code is taking up this time, but it seems that the New Relic agent doesn't report enough detail to show what it is, at least in a Play Framework 2 application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with how NewRelic collects data, however `deadLetters` is a special Actor that receives "all messages that were sent to a dead (or non existent) Actor". You can read more about [dead letters in the official docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#Dead_Letters).

For example you can [subscribe to these dead letters and print them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902900/how-to-view-akka-dead-letters) (which should give you enough information to then track down their source and fix it). A typical case where many dead letters may be encountered is when you're sending messages to an Actor which has stopped, but someone is still sending messages to it - this you should be able to detect once printing the deadletters.