# How to view akka dead letters

Tags: scala, akka, dead-letter

I've created an Actor that performs some basic operations and appears to be working correctly - however I'm seeing the following show up in my logs regularly

```
[INFO] [05/28/2014 14:24:00.673] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://application/deadLetters] Message [akka.actor.Status$Failure] from Actor[akka://application/user/trigger_worker_supervisor#-2119432352] to Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I would like to actually view the contents of the Failure to establish what exactly is throwing a `Failure`, however I can't quite figure out how to view them.

Reading through the Akka documentation it mentions how to disable the dead-letter warning in the logs, but not how to actually write a handler to process them.

Is there a simple way to actually catch anything sent to dead-letters?

Comment: See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/event-bus.html#event-stream-scala. The example code block shows how to register an `Actor` to receive the dead letters.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Missed that while reading the docs - might as well post as a full answer and I'll flag it as the winner.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @wingedsubmariner, you can subscribe to the `DeadLetter` event on the main system `EventStream` to be notified when deadletters happen and be able to react to that situation in a more custom manner.  In order to subscribe, the code would look like this:

```
context.system.eventStream.subscribe(myListenerActorRef, classOf[DeadLetter])
```

Then, the receive for that listener actor could look something like this:

```
def receive = {
  case DeadLetter(msg, from, to) =>
    //Do my custom stuff here
}
```

The structure of the `DeadLetter` class is:

```
case class DeadLetter(message: Any, sender: ActorRef, recipient: ActorRef)
```